# Can't find google-play-services version that corresponds to firebase-messaging version

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

From what I understand, in order to use firebase messaging I need my `google-play-services` version to match my `firebase-messaging` version in my app's `build.gradle`. According to [Google's Firebase setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) the firebase version I should use is `17.3.0`, so I figure I'm supposed to use `google-play-services` version `17.3.0`, but that doesn't work because Android Studio can't find that version:

[image: missing google play services dependencies]

Here is how I've added them to `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'

    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I understand, in order to use firebase messaging I need my
>   google-play-services version to match my firebase-messaging version

That is no longer true, google recently changed to semantic versioning so libraries are no longer tied to the same version. `12.0.1` I believe was the last version that you could make the same version for everything play services related and everything else must follow the new versioning system

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

You can check googles maven repository for the latest version of any library

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Also you should not include all of google play services in your project and you should only declare the libraries you need as this makes your app smaller.

Comment: How can I tell what libraries I need? As far as I know, I only *need* firebase. Am I supposed to know all my dependencies' dependencies?

Comment: If you are using just firebase I believe all you need is `play-services-base` but I am not 100% certain. Just look at what the errors say when you remove the large play services package when you build your app

Comment: This pages tells you what you need to include in your `build.gradle` for each Firebase component. You most likely need the following (core & messaging) - `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3` & `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0` --- https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @mattdonders Adding those gives me this error: `Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.3.`. Tried adding `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:16.0.3'`, but now I'm just getting `Cannot invoke method split() on null object`.

Comment: @SimpleJ check your project-level (not app-level) gradle config. There should be a Play Services classpath there that's probably highlighted as being outdated. Select it, hit Alt+Enter and choose to update it.

Comment: @TheWanderer Looks like that fixed my build issues. Firebase is now doing nothing without errors, but at least it builds I guess